# Record counter by condition in one query

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to count the reviews by rating count before calling the get (-> get) method to get all those counters by querying the database without any calculations on the server? My solution at the moment:

```
$allReviews = Review::query()
            ->where('product_id', $data['product_id'])
            ->whereNotNull('published_at')
            ->get();
$fiveStars = count($allReviews->where('rating', 5));
        $fourStars = count($allReviews->where('rating', 4));
        $threeStars = count($allReviews->where('rating', 3));
        $twoStars = count($allReviews->where('rating', 2));
        $oneStar = count($allReviews->where('rating', 1));
        $overallRating = ($fiveStars * 5 + $fourStars * 4 + $threeStars * 3 + $twoStars * 2 + $oneStar) / (($fiveStars + $fourStars + $threeStars + $twoStars + $oneStar));
```

Comment: Are you using `$allReviews` for anything else in the request or it is just for the ratings?

Comment: @Rwd only ratings,i gets all records  in another query

Answer (score 1):

You could use `groupBy` and `pluck`:

```
$ratings = Review::query()
    ->selectRaw('rating, COUNT(*) as amount')
    ->where('product_id', $data['product_id'])
    ->whereNotNull('published_at')
    ->groupBy('rating')
    ->pluck('amount', 'rating');

$fiveStars = $rating[5] ?? 0;
$fourStars = $rating[4] ?? 0;
$threeStars = $rating[3] ?? 0;
$twoStars = $rating[2] ?? 0;
$oneStar = $rating[1] ?? 0;
```